# Required validator not working with async field

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm having a problem that seems to be caused by the "required" validator not working with a form field that is updated asynchronously from an AngularFire database.  When I try to edit an existing user, even though the "username" and "email" inputs both contain the existing user's values, Angular seems to be considering each `<input>` empty until I type in them.  I can see that behavior because the Submit button is disabled until I type in each `<input>`.

Here's my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { User } from './user';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'user-form.component.html'
})
export class UserFormComponent {
    key;
    item;
    form: FormGroup;
    user = new User();

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _router: Router, private _route:ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.key = params["key"];
        })

        if (!this.key) {
            this.title = "New User";
        }
        else {
            // This is the path that is followed for editing an existing user
            this.title = "Edit User";
            this.item = this.db.object(this.key).valueChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my view

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="user.username" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" value={{(item|async)?.name}}>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.username.touched && !form.controls.username.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
            Username is required
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="user.email" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email" value={{(item|async)?.email}}>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.touched && !form.controls.email.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
        </div>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I can further confirm that Angular sees my `<input>`s as empty because if I tab into one of the fields and then tab out of it without typing anything, the `<div>` that shows the error message appears.

Why does Angular consider both of my `<input>`s empty when I'm editing an existing user?  Is there a different way that I have to handle the "required" validator since I'm using the `async` pipe?

Comment: Did you consider to use AsyncValidator?

Comment: I changed the validators to AsyncValidators like `this.form = fb.group({username: ['', {asyncValidator: Validators.required}], email: ['', {asyncValidator: Validators.required}]})`, but I'm still having a problem that in my `submit` method, `this.user.username` and `this.user.email` are `undefined` unless I type a value into the `<input>` controls, even though both inputs *do* visually have values in them on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain your console should be full of errors. You're not allowed to use ngModel within a FormGroup. You either use template driven forms (FormsModule) or model driven forms (ReactiveFormsModule), but you can't use both within each other.

Remove the ngModel and value stuff. To set the value of a form when using `ReactiveFormsModule`, you use the methods `setValue()` or `patchValue()`:

```
this.form.setValue({
    username: 'example',
    email: 'example@gmail.com'
});
```

Or you can set a single FormControl value:

```
this.form.get('username').setValue('example')
```

Comment: "You're not allowed to use ngModel within a FormGroup" Why wouldn't it be allowed? I wouldn't recommend it, but it's possible to use.

Comment: No it doesn't: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcmvmc?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I've always gotten the error because I use one or the other. I hadn't thought of using both on the same control because it doesn't make any sense. But I j ust realized that's what he was trying to do after checking your example. But yeah, if you remove formControlName, you're going to get the error: "ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive."

Comment: yes, that error will be produced, but you claim that they cannot be used together, which is incorrect ;) But yes, definitely not recommended to have two bindings.

Comment: @AJT_82 Could you elaborate what you mean about two bindings?  This code is an example from an Angular book that I'm reading.  Is the author doing something poorly?

Comment: @BenRubin Yes, I would say the author is doing something poorly actually :) You have two different bindings `ngModel` and `formControl`. There is no point in having those two together, and sometimes having these two together can cause unexpected issues. To even use these two together you need to have both `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` imported, since `ngModel` directive is not even included in `ReactiveFormsModule`, so I'd say that is one more hint that they shouldn't be used together :) So choose either templatedriven form with `ngModel` or reactive form with form controls :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for the explanation.  I'm pretty new to Angular, so I'm still a little shaky on some of these concepts.  I was looking at the documentation on angular.io yesterday to try to figure this out, and I was confused with this book code because it appeared to be using elements of both template-driven forms and of reactive forms according to angular.io.  Your explanation is very helpful because it confirms that the author's example isn't following the documentation on angular.io.  Thank you.